# Doctrine mongodb between dates

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

Here is my field im trying to get with doctrine

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5512f2ae73d151bb528b4589"),
    "name" : "Strandby-1",
    "enddate" : ISODate("2015-03-31T22:00:00.000Z"),
    "startdate" : ISODate("2015-03-24T23:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Now Im trying to do find it inside my repository

```
$time = new \DateTime();
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder();
$query
    ->field('startdate')->gte($time)
    ->field('enddate')->lte($time)
;
return $query->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

But im just getting `null`

I always tried where `$time = new \MongoDate();` but still getting `null`

Comment: It may be OT, but I don't see the `league` field in your object.

Comment: Just removed it, as this does not have any relevance to the query, and the query is still null

Answer (score 4):

Doctrine also converts DateTime, string time or timestamp to MongoDate by itself,
look at doctrine\mongodb-odm\lib\Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Types\DateType.php

```
public static function getDateTime($value)
{
    $datetime = false;
    $exception = null;

    if ($value instanceof \DateTime || $value instanceof \DateTimeInterface) {
        return $value;
    ...
```

Which is called in

```
public function convertToDatabaseValue($value)
{
    if ($value === null || $value instanceof \MongoDate) {
        return $value;
    }

    $datetime = self::getDateTime($value);
```

So the problem is not in a date type. Your problem is in logic.

You are trying to get an object with startdate >= now >= enddate

Try this:

```
->field('startdate')->lte($time)
->field('enddate')->gte($time)
```